# WiX v4 - execommand not working - works fine on command line

Tags: cmd, wix, custom-action

I have a custom action which runs a packaged exe :

```
<CustomAction Id="RunIt" 
          Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
          ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyEXE.exe /silent >C:\output.log" 
          Execute="deferred" 
          Impersonate="no" 
          Return="asyncWait" />
```

the exe works fine - the /silent command works fine - however the >C:\output.log doesn't seem to do anything.

When i include the >output command, it does extend the install duration, which i would expect - as it needs the time to write the log, but it still doesnt output anything.

I previously had a .cmd which contained the full execommand(and this was included in the custom action instead) - this worked fine - but i would like to try and reduce unnecessary files if i can, and i dont see why this wouldnt work.

Comment: What's the trailing `>` for, here `>C:\output.log >`?

Comment: No, `>C:\output.log`, which is lazy syntax for `1>"C:\output.log"` redirects stdOut to `C:\output.log`. There should not be another redirection handle.

Comment: @Compo yeah sorry thats just a issue in the question didnt see it - still doesnt work without

Comment: You have an executable file packaged to install, then you should identify which type of installer program created it, and use any built-in logging options for that type of package.

Comment: oh, i assumed if the logging works when running that same prompt in cmd it should be fine?

Comment: Do you mean it logs to the file? or to the Command Prompt window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>C:\output.log` syntax is interpreted by cmd.exe. When you use an exe CustomAction, the Windows Installer straight up calls `::CreateProcess()`. `::CreateProcess()` does none of the syntax processing that cmd.exe does, so you're *probably* getting the values `>C:\output.log` as one of the parameters input to your program.

You either need to launch cmd.exe to then launch your .exe, or your .exe needs to provide an option to log to a file.